# LINQ group by date and then order by property, to get the highest amount?

Tags: c#, linq

Assume this model:

```
public class Model
{
    public DateTime Created { get; set; }
    public int Quota { get; set; }
}
```

I need to specify a specific month of a year, and extract a summary of `Quota`, but I need to only grab ONE per day of the month (maximum is 31 and minimum is 28 in the list, depending on the date), and that one has to be the entry where `Quota` is highest. Example:

```
[{
  created: "10/1/2019",
  quota: 5
}, {
  created: "10/1/2019",
  quota: 6
}, {
  created: "10/2/2019",
  quota: 1
}]
```

In that example, I would get two items back:

```
[{
  created: "10/1/2019",
  quota: 6
}, {
  created: "10/2/2019",
  quota: 1
}]
```

Because `Quota = 6` is higher than `Quota = 5` and because they're on the same date (1st of October).

```
public List<Model> GetMonthlyData(int year, int month)
{
    var list = await _dbContext
        .Where(x => x.Created.Year == year && x.Created.Month == month)
        .GroupBy(x => x.Created.Day)
        .OrderByDescending(x => x.Quota)
        .Select(x => x.First())
        .ToListAsync();

    return list;
}
```

I want something like that. Group by the day, order by descending (so the first item has the highest quota), select the first in the group, and convert them into a list. However, I can't figure out how to do this. I'm sure it's really simple, but I can't see where my bug is.

Comment: GroupBy returns a composite object: a key (i.e. the day) and an enumeration of the items related to the key (i.e. the original items).

Comment: `GroupBy(...).Select(grp => grp.OrderByDescending(x => x.Quota).First()).ToList()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use GroupBy with below Select()

```
 var test = mList
        .Where(x => x.Created.Year == year && x.Created.Month == month)   //Filter your record based on condition
        .GroupBy(x => x.Created.Day) //Group by Created.Day
        .Select(x => x.Aggregate((z1, z2) => z1.Quota > z2.Quota ? z1 : z2))   // Aggreate function to Get object with max Qouta
        .ToList();   //Convert into List
```

Output:

```
10/1/2019    6
10/2/2019    1
```

---

I used below linq functions,

[.Where()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.where?view=netframework-4.8) : Where clause to filter records based on condition in your case it is `x.Created.Year == year && x.Created.Month == month`

[.GroupBy()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.groupby?view=netframework-4.8) : Group element based on predicate i.e Group filtered record based on `x.Created.Day`

[.Aggregate()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.aggregate?view=netframework-4.8) : Apply specified logic on elements, here I used [ternary operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator) to get entire object based on highest `Qouta`

[.Select()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?view=netframework-4.8) : To get new form of object.

[.Net Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/d0JnrW)

Comment: Ah yes, do the OrderByDescending inside the Select. That's where I was wrong. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I was struggling to write select statement in fiddle, thanks to @Jimi his comment gave me hint

Comment: `Max()` *flattens* the type to a value, though, so you may need a projection. It depends on the intented result. `OrderBy().Last()` returns the original type (there are other means, though).

Comment: @Jimi, I realized while writing fiddle, I updated to use `.Aggregate`

Answer (score 2):

Here are two options.

```
 var list = data
        .GroupBy(x => x.Created.Date)
        .Select( g => g.OrderByDescending(x => x.Quota).First());
```

Option 2.

```
var list = data
        .GroupBy(x => x.Created.Date)
        .Select( g => new { Created = g.Key, Quota = g.Max( x => x.Quota)});
```

## Test

```
var json = @"[{
    created: ""10/1/2019"",
    quota: 5
}, {
    created: ""10/1/2019"",
    quota: 6
}, {    
    created: ""10/2/2019"",
    quota: 1
},{
    created: ""10/2/2019"",
    quota: 7
}]";

var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Model>>(json);

 var list = data
        .GroupBy(x => x.Created.Date)
        .Select( g => g.OrderByDescending(x => x.Quota).First());

 foreach( var l in list ) Console.WriteLine($"{l.Created} with {l.Quota}");
```

```
// .NETCoreApp,Version=v3.0
1/10/2019 00:00:00 with 6
2/10/2019 00:00:00 with 7
```